# Google App Engine + Django + filetransfers failing

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-rest-framework

I've had a web application online for several months now on Google App Engine with no problems. All that changed Tuesday, when all file uploads have started failing with CSRF problems.

In essence, I call `prepare_upload` to get a one-time URL from the Google Cloud Storage, the user posts their file to that URL, and GCS then calls a URL in my code to complete the process so I have a handle on the uploaded file.

The mobile apps are authenticating using Django Rest Framework's token authentication mechanism by sending an auth token in the `Authorization` header of every request. This header appears to be stripped starting a few days ago, but I'm not sure if that's the actual issue. The fact that CSRF checks are failing indicates to me that the token authentication step is being skipped and session authentication is being used instead.

I'm baffled. Does anyone know with certainty whether this header is stripped by Google Cloud Storage, and if so how I can override that or work around it?

Here is my `prepare_upload` utility function:

```
from google.appengine.ext.blobstore import create_upload_url

def prepare_upload(request, url, **kwargs):
    return create_upload_url(
        url,
        gs_bucket_name = settings.GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET
    ), {}
```

Comment: By `Cloud Store` do you mean `Google Cloud Storage`?

Comment: Also can you let me know where the `prepare_upload` function comes from? I'm curious if it's using signed URLs.

Comment: Yes, GCS. Added my prepare_upload function to the question.

Comment: Thanks, a few more questions: which URL is giving you the CSRF error? Is it when you upload the file (the `/_ah/upload` URL) or is it the redirect back to your application? Does the upload work via web?

Comment: Sure! It's the redirect back to my application. The upload to GCS succeeds, but my endpoint is not receiving the Authentication header (which causes the app to fall-back to web session authentication) and there is no web session (coming from a mobile app accessing the REST framework directly without a web session), so the CSRF check fails.

Comment: How is your client sending these requests? What language/client library/http client are you using? Can you log the requests to verify that the client is indeed sending the headers to the redirected location?

Comment: Different clients are all seeing the same behavior, but the one I have the most insight into is using python and the requests package in the interpreter. When I send the request along with the desired headers, the headers appear to not be included in what's forwarded to the app on the redirect. I have not yet turned on any logging in the middleware to see what exactly is received from GCS.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll try to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be resolved. See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/CCL_9sgjdu0/segjM0KnAwAJ).

Comment: That was exactly the issue. In the meantime we re-released all our apps to pass the user security token as part of the form submitted to GCS so that we are not dependent on the Authorization header anymore, so now we have graceful failover if the header is stripped during file upload. Thanks for all your help in identifying what was going on!